# How to fix both the branch length and topology in MrBayes

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogeny

I am wondering is it possible to fix both of them in MrBayes at the same time?

I see some previous posts about fixing the tree topology is first to define the tree and then use "fixed" function like (assuming we have defined species_topology already)

The first line fix the tree topology and the second line defines the probability of moving to other topologies is zero.

```
Prset topologypr=fixed(species_topology);
propset eTBR(Tau)$prob=0;
```

I am wondering can I do something similar to fix the branch length as well?
In terms of the proposal move to the branch lengths, I think we should use

```
propset nslider(V)$prob=0
```

But I am not sure what to put in:

```
Prset brlenpr=
```

Thanks in advance! I have searched a lot of posts in MrBayes's mailing list but they did not have questions about fixing both of them at the same time. Usually, they just fix the topology.

Comment: try in [https://www.biostars.org/](https://www.biostars.org/) , question have more options to be answered

Comment: Thank you very much! I will also try there. Hopefully can get some help:)

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a lot of MrBayes tutorials, I find a way to achieve this by myself. In MrBayes 3.2, it allows us to fix both the tree topology and the branch length. We can set the prior of both topology and branch length to a fixed tree in newick format and then define the probability of moving from the initial state as zero. Remember you must define your fixed tree with fixed branch length in the nexus file where you save your sequence information data.

For example, you can define your tree in this way:

```
begin trees;
tree tree_1 = ((t6:0.3279207193,t9:0.9545036491):0.04205953353,t5:0.8895393161,(((t4:0.6557057991,t10:0.7085304682):0.9942697766,t3:0.5440660247):0.6405068138,((t8:0.1471136473,(t2:0.9022990451,t1:0.6907052784):0.9630242325):0.2891597373,t7:0.7954674177):0.5941420204):0.9388911405);
;
end;
```

Then in your MrBayes template you can use the following commands to fix the tree topology and branch length:

```
prset topologypr=fixed(tree_1);
prset brlenspr=fixed(tree_1);
```

Tau represents the topology and V denotes the branch length.